# Centralized way of organizing urls in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Forgive me if I am asking an obvious question (maybe I missed it in the docs somewhere?) but has anyone found a good way to organize their URLs in [Jersey](http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Main) Java framework?

I mean organizing them centrally in your Java source code, so that you can be sure there are not two classes that refer to the same Url.

For example django has a really nice [regex-based](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) matching.
I was thinking of doing something like an enum:

```
enum Urls{
    CARS  ("cars"),
    CAR_INFO ("car", "{info}");

    public Urls(String path, String args) 
    ...
}
```

but you can imagine that gets out of hand pretty quickly if you have urls like:

```
cars/1/wheels/3
```

where you need multiple path-ids interleaved with one another...

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experiences with Jersey, when I tried to annotate two places with the same `@Path`, I had compilation errors and it wouldn't run.  This might not always be the case, so the following might help:

You can get an `application.wadl` file from your Jersey app by simply requesting it from you web resource:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/application.wadl
```

or if you prefixed your web services under `/ws/`

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/ws/application.wadl
```

---

The application.wadl file is an XML file that shows you all of your resources in your running application, as well as what methods you can call on a resource.  See [the following resource](http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/WADL) on how this file is laid out.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about wadl.

Comment: Looks like there really is no good way to organized URLs in jersey. In any case - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well - I assume you have a @Path on each resource? This means you don't have to keep track of URLs across your entire application, rather just within each class - which is relatively easy if you annotate the interface.

Using enums won't work - you can only put contants into an annotation, but using a class holding final static String could work.

```
public class UrlConst {
  public final static RESOURCE_MY_RESOURCE="/resource";
  public final static RESOURCE_MY_RESOURCE2="/resource";
  public final static OP_GET_ALL="/";
  public final static OP_GET_BY_ID="/{id}";
}

@Path(UrlConst.RESOURCE_MY_RESOURCE)
public interface MyResource {

 @GET
 @Path(UrlConst.OP_GET_ALL)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public ObjectList getAll();

 @GET
 @Path(UrlConst.OP_GET_BY_ID)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public Object get(@PathParam("id") int id);

}

@Path(UrlConst.RESOURCE_MY_RESOURCE2)
public interface MyResource2 {

 @GET
 @Path(UrlConst.OP_GET_ALL)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public ObjectList getAll();

 @GET
 @Path(UrlConst.OP_GET_BY_ID)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public Object get(@PathParam("id") int id);

}
```

etc.

Comment: Woot, thanks for letting me know about javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType constant! I was using my own :-)

Comment: About your answer - I see what you are saying, but it looks a bit clumsy to me. I'll think about it, thanks.